How can I inspect CPU usage of Safari in iPad
I have a web application, then I want to check the cpu of the app running in iPad.
I used Xcode but i can't see anything related Safari.
I used Web Inspector (with this guidline: Mobile Safari Web Inspector) but I could't find anything like the video below
my Mac: 
Do we have anyway can resolve my problem?


From your iPad -> Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector -> Toggle on
From your mac -> Safari -> Settings -> Advanced -> Show Features for web developers
From your iPad -> Open Safari -> Open the web page you want to inspect
From your mac -> Safari -> Develp menu -> Your iPad -> the web page under the safari section


Then you can inspect your iPad Safari with your Mac Safari inspector:

Note: Make sure to have your iPad Safari open in the foreground and keep the device unlocked

sr mate. I did as you said but it doesn't work you can see my  the image in my question :(
